# How set API KEY in Google Translate Node.js code

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, api-key

I'm trying to create a Node.js code that uses Google Translate API.
I got the code below from the [Google doc](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text)

But when I run it, it says `Error: The request is missing a valid API key.`
I have the key, but I don't know how and where to set it.

```
async function translate() { // Imports the Google Cloud client library
    const { Translate } = require('@google-cloud/translate');

    // Creates a client
    const translate = new Translate();

    /**
     * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
     */
    const text = 'Hello, world!';
    const target = 'ru';

    // Translates the text into the target language. "text" can be a string for
    // translating a single piece of text, or an array of strings for translating
    // multiple texts.
    let [translations] = await translate.translate(text, target);
    translations = Array.isArray(translations) ? translations : [translations];
    console.log('Translations:');
    translations.forEach((translation, i) => {
        console.log(`${text[i]} => (${target}) ${translation}`);
    });
}
translate()
```

Comment: Why i got
:
 const transl = new Translate();
                ^

TypeError: Translate is not a constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page on setting up authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) explains that you need to download a credentials file from the create service account key page. This can then be added to your path (`.bashrc`) as follows:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

Alternately, you could add the line above to a `.env` file on your project root and source it when you are running the application:

```
. ./.env
npm start
```

or

```
sh -ac '. ./.env; npm start'
```

Comment: Worked very well!! Just one thing... on mac the command is ". ./.env"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will edit. We can just say the same for both Mac and Linux.

Comment: where did you find the documentation that shows that `export GOOGLE...` is the right way? It works, but how did you find it?

Comment: @YuriAps the way Google does this has definitely changed over the years. You can now use `gcloud auth login` which will set these environment variables for you.

Answer (score 5):

1. create api-key see documentation [create api key doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#create)

2. use it like:

`import { v2 } from '@google-cloud/translate';
const translateClint = new v2.Translate({
    projectId:'your-projectId-here',
    key: 'your-api-key-here',
});`

I don't check it for v3, but I see the same interface:

`new v3.TranslationServiceClient({
key:"may be works",
projectId:"may be works"
})`

Comment: Please note that this only works if you are using the v2 API client.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this [Google Authentication Page](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) to add the key

> 1. In the GCP Console, go to the Create service account key page.
> 2. From the Service account list, select New service account.
> 3. In the Service account name field, enter a name.
> 4. From the Role list, select Project > Owner. Click
> 5. Create. A JSON file that contains your key downloads to your computer.

and

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH to key downloaded]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... no environment variables AND please... add this file to your .gitignore

```
   import * as credentials from 'credentials.json'; 
...
    const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;
    const translationApi = new Translate({
                    projectId:'your-project-id',
                    credentials:credentials
                });
```